# Check if Range includes named Ranges

Tags: excel, vba

### What I have:

1. Named range *"Type"* with 1 row and multiple columns
2. Named ranges *"Group1"*, *"Group2"* etc.
3. *Group* range objects are **in** *"Type"* range (what I'm trying to say that these *Group* ranges share the same row and columns with *Type* range, but have fewer columns)

### What I need:

I need to add all *"Group#"* local names in the list box I have on UserForm
So probably I need an array of names or a realy good loop.

### What I did:

```
For Each NamedRange In ThisWorkbook.Names
    If InStr(1, NamedRange.NameLocal, "Group") <> 0 Then
            If Not (Application.Intersect(Range(NamedRange.NameLocal), Range("Type")) Is Nothing) Then
                Main.List_Groups.AddItem NamedRange.NameLocal
            End If
    End If
Next
```

It does what I need *partly*. It also adds named ranges that are *bigger* than *Type* range where I need range of added name to be *within* *Type* range.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you mean you want every cell in Group1 to be inside Type then perhaps you could write a custom function which loops through every cell of the former and checks that it intersects with the latter. Then call that UDF.

Comment: @SJR I thought about that, but, to be honest, with 5 already existing Groups (and more incoming) each consisting of about 10 columns, looping through every cell in them looks irrational to me (since For Each Loop goes *Left->Right*, *Up->Bottom* it will execute without error and will detect one after looping through first row). I was hoping for a secret range property or something ^^'

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "will detect one after looping through first row". You don't necessarily need to loop through every cell because as soon as you find a cell in Group1 which is not in Type you exit the function (so it returns a Boolean). However, I am not aware of a shortcut. It might be so secret that nobody has told me about it though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can check if the Adress of your Intersected Range is the adress of your group-range. If it is, it lies completely within your type-range:

So instead of

```
If Not (Application.Intersect(Range(NamedRange.NameLocal), Range("Type")) Is Nothing) Then
```

use

```
If Application.Intersect(Range(namedrange.NameLocal), Range("Type")).Address = Range(namedrange.NameLocal).Address Then
```

Comment: Oh, genius - so much better than my solution, Kudos!

Comment: Nice one, which completely invalidates my comments.

Comment: Boy, wish I could upvote more, best I can do is to accept, thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Application.Intersect(Range(NamedRange.NameLocal), Range("Type")) is not nothing if any part of the two ranges overlap - to prove that one is contained within the other, you should check that namedrange does not overlap with the ranges above, below, to the left and to the right of Type. (Obviously if type is at the top or left of the sheet you can omit some tests. So add  more if statements testing intersect with appropriate ranges - so (if Test is fixed) something like

```
 If  (Application.Intersect(Range(NamedRange.NameLocal), Range("A2:f2")) Is Nothing then
```

If Test is variable then The range at the top would be

```
 Range(cells(range("test").cells(1,1).row-1,Range("Test").cells(1,1).column), _
        cells(range("test").cells(1,1).row-1,Range("Test").cells(1,1).column + range("test").columns.count -1)))
```